# How get data from mySQL using string with params?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, get

I've iOS App which should receive JSON data from MySQL database using string with parameters and PHP script. String looks like this: NSString *getDataURL1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myhost.com/jsoncar.php?carOne=%@", _carOneToServer]; where _carOneToServer is string containts particular car model which user has selected in my App, for example "AUDI A3 1.8TFSI". In MySQL database I've got exactly same car model.

PHP script should be checking for matching models between ULR query and MySQL data base and returns parameters for this car model.

So far I wrote some code but it returns []. I understand I need variables to work with, but I don't know PHP, so need your help guys. Thank you.

PHP script:

```
$host = "localhost"; //Your database host server
$db = "MyDataBase"; //Your database name
$user = "user"; //Your database user
$pass = "password"; //Your password


$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
//Check to see if we can connect to the server
if(!$connection) {
die("Database server connection failed.");
} else {
    //Attempt to select the database
    $dbconnect = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);

    //Check to see if we could select the database
if(!$dbconnect) {
    die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
    } else {


        if (isset($_GET['carOne'])) {

    $carModel = $_GET[carOne];

        $query = "SELECT carFuelEconomy, carPurchasePrice FROM cars
    WHERE carModel = $carModel";
        $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        $records = array();

//Loop through all our records and add them to our array
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset)) {
        $records[] = $r;
        }
//Output the data as JSON
echo json_encode($records);
}
}   
}
```

MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE cars
(

id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL auto_increment,
carModel VARCHAR(255),
carFuelEconomy int,
carPurchasePrice int,
distanceTraveledDaily int,
lenghtOfOwnership int

);

-- Insert data into our table

INSERT INTO cars(carModel, carFuelEconomy, carPurchasePrice, distanceTraveledDaily, lenghtOfOwnership)
VALUE ('AUDI A3 1.8TFSI', 27, 30795, 30, 76);

INSERT INTO cars(carModel, carFuelEconomy, carPurchasePrice, distanceTraveledDaily, lenghtOfOwnership)
VALUE ('AUDI A3 2.0TDI', 36, 33495, 30, 76);

INSERT INTO cars(carModel, carFuelEconomy, carPurchasePrice, distanceTraveledDaily, lenghtOfOwnership)
VALUE ('AUDI A3 2.0TFSI', 33, 34095, 30, 76);
```

Comment: change $carModel = $_GET[carOne]; to  $carModel = $_GET['carOne'];

Comment: Don't forget check my answer as correct ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 errors, change this:

```
$carModel = $_GET[carOne];
$query = "SELECT carFuelEconomy, carPurchasePrice FROM cars
WHERE carModel = $carModel";
```

for this:

```
$carModel = $_GET['carOne'];
$query = "SELECT carFuelEconomy, carPurchasePrice FROM cars
WHERE carModel = '$carModel'";
```

EDIT. Code complete (1.php):

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; //Your database host server
$db = "YourDataBase"; //Your database name
$user = "YourUser"; //Your database user
$pass = "YourPass"; //Your password


$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
//Check to see if we can connect to the server
if(!$connection) {
die("Database server connection failed.");
} else {
    //Attempt to select the database
    $dbconnect = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);

    //Check to see if we could select the database
if(!$dbconnect) {
    die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
    } else {


        if (isset($_GET['carOne'])) {

$carModel = $_GET['carOne'];
$query = "SELECT carFuelEconomy, carPurchasePrice FROM cars
WHERE carModel = '$carModel'";

        $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        $records = array();

//Loop through all our records and add them to our array
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset)) {
        $records[] = $r;
        }
//Output the data as JSON
echo json_encode($records);
}
}   
}

?>
```

In your browser:

> http://localhost/1.php?carOne=AUDI%20A3%201.8TFSI

Output:

```
[{"carFuelEconomy":"27","carPurchasePrice":"30795"}]
```

Comment: @SergeyZ I test it and it works, don't forget check as correct.

Comment: Update: got error "Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/xsdadmin/public_html/jsoncar.php on line 32
[]"

Comment: Ok, I'll play around it, will try figured out where I made mistake.

Comment: @SergeyZ I edit with the whole code, the link in the browser and the output, check it and tell me.

Comment: Quick question, do I need quotation  mark here: if (isset($_GET[carOne])) for carOne?

Comment: @SergeyZ yes, you need your code like this:  if (isset($_GET['carOne'])) don't forget check as correct ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the connection from when you call the query. For instance,

```
$resultset = mysql_query($query);
```

instead of:

```
$resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);
```